# Client not connecting to server via socket module

Tags: python, sockets

I was trying to make something to tell my brother to come home from his friends because he's always late. I tested it on our car's wifi and the client isn't connecting. I didn't just use the "0.0.0.0" That's just what I found to try, but it didn't work.

Edit: I already have port forwarded*

Server:

```
from socket import *


def listToString(s):
    str1 = " "
    return (str1.join(s))


s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 6050))
s.listen(1)
clientsocket, address = s.accept()
print(f"Jacob has turned on his computer from the ip address {address}")

while True:
    command = input('> ')
    if command.upper() == 'SHUTDOWN':
        clientsocket.send('shutdown'.encode('utf-8'))

    elif command.upper() == 'ALERT':
        clientsocket.send('alert'.encode('utf-8'))
        response = clientsocket.recv(2048)
        print(f'Jacob > {response.decode("utf-8")}')

    elif 'CMDEXE' in command.upper():
        clientsocket.send(command.encode('utf-8'))

    elif 'CLBL' in command.upper():
        text = input('>> ')
        clientsocket.send(f'clbl {text}'.encode('utf-8'))
        print(f'Jacob > {clientsocket.recv(2048).decode("utf-8")}')
        continue
```

Client:

```
from socket import *
from os import *
from tkinter import *


def sendresponse(message):
    s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    root.destroy()


def send(message):
    s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))


def listToString(s):
    str1 = " "
    return (str1.join(s))


IP = "(IPV4)"
PORT = 6050

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((IP, PORT))

while True:
    msg = s.recv(2048)
    if msg.decode('utf-8').upper() == 'SHUTDOWN':
        system('cmd /c "shutdown /s /f /t 0"')

    elif msg.decode('utf-8').upper() == 'ALERT':
        system('TASKKILL /F /IM "Windows10Universal.exe"')
        system('TASKKILL /F /IM "RobloxPlayerBeta.exe"')
        system('TASKKILL /F /IM "chrome.exe"')
        system('TASKKILL /F /IM "Minecraft.Windows.exe"')
        system('TASKKILL /F /IM "Valorant.exe"')
        system('TASKKILL /F /IM "Steam.exe"')
        system('TASKKILL /F /IM "osu!.exe"')
        system('TASKKILL /F /IM "Among Us.exe"')
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('500x500')
        button1 = Button(root, text='Ok. On my way!', command=lambda: s.send('Ok. On my way!'.encode('utf-8')))
        button2 = Button(root, text='NO!!', command=lambda: s.send('NO!!'.encode('utf-8')))
        label = Label(root, text="JACOB IT IS TIME TO COME HOME!")
        label.pack()
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        root.mainloop()

    elif 'CMDEXE' in msg.decode('utf-8').upper():
        command = msg.decode('utf-8').split(' ')
        command.remove('cmdexe')
        system(listToString(command))

    elif 'CLBL' in msg.decode('utf-8').upper():
        text = msg.decode('utf-8')
        text = text.split(' ')
        text.remove('clbl')
        text = listToString(text)
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry('500x500')
        sendb = Button(root, command=lambda: sendresponse(rese.get()), text='Send')
        rese = Entry(root)
        label = Label(root, text=text)
        label.pack()
        rese.pack()
        sendb.pack()
        root.mainloop()
```

This code works on my local network if I change the IP's.

Comment: *"I was trying to __make something__ to tell my brother to come home from his friends because he's always late."* - that's not a usable description of what your program should do. Basically there is a useless description and then an undocumented code dump where most parts of the code are likely not related to your problem at all. If the client isn't connecting than either the given server IP is wrong or there is something in between client and server which is disallowing connections, like a firewall. The problem is likely not in your code.

Comment: To connect different computer on a WAN you need to use something known as *Port forawrding*